# Spring 4.0.6 release - @RequestMapping issue

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I have downloaded (using Maven) Spring release 4.0.6. How ever in the Controller class I got an error.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

The error was that @RequestMapping was not found. STC/Eclipse itself gave a suggestion to resolve it. And when I clicked on the suggestion it mentioned about copying some thing to /.m2/repository. And then the error was fixed as well.

What exactly did STC/Eclipse IDE do?

Comment: Please note STC/Ecplise also added the below packages. This I understand is to get the class references. I was confused on the copying of some files to .m2 folder.
_import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod_;

Comment: Clean and rebuild all your project again.

Comment: @user3831696: next time you should give your question a more meaningful name, that is indicating what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that STS/Eclipse added the `spring-webmvc` dependency to your pom.xml.

This triggered maven to donload that depency from maven central to your local maven repository cache (.m2 folder).

Because the `spring-webmvc` dependency was added to your pom.xml its the jar and its classes becomes available for your project.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. But can I decide where to download the jar files? I mean why should it only download to the local user .m2 folder. Would it be possible to download them to 'D:\MyFavouriteJars'.

Comment: @user3831696: the .m2 folder is managed by maven, therefore you should NOT use it for something else or manipulate them. Anyway there is (or can be created) a settings.xml in the root of the .m2 folder, there you can specify where to place the repositoy directory. http://blogs.plexibus.com/2008/03/11/how-to-change-your-local-maven-repository/